# C++ structure taking template signature?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, signature, typename

I have been asked to do this "thing" work :

```
FunctSignature<int(const std::string &str)>::type f= &thisIsAFunction;
f("coucou");
```

To achieve this, they ask me to do :

> First : Declare a structure taking a template
>
> Then : Declare the same structure as before but this time you must specialize it partially.
>
> Finaly : This specialisation will have the form of the signature of the above function. The declaration part which is templated will declare each of its signature members.

If anybody has an idear how to do this thing work... HELP !!!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the material, and the notes, that were taught in your class the week, or so, before this homework assignment was handed out. I'm sure you will find sufficient information and explanation of the necessary course material that's necessary to complete this homework assignment.

Comment: The subject has been blured intentionnaly... Any ideas or hints who woul'd led toward the solution woul'd be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows a basic implementation which doesn't involve variadic template:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct FunctSignature { };

template<class Ret, class Arg>
struct FunctSignature<Ret(Arg)> {
    using type = Ret(*)(Arg);
};

int thisIsAFunction(const std::string &str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    FunctSignature<int(const std::string &str)>::type f= &thisIsAFunction;
    f("cocou");
}
```

Here instead a variadic template based one:

```
template<typename T>
struct FunctSignature { };

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct FunctSignature<Ret(Args...)> {
    using type = Ret(*)(Args...);
};
```